# Как сохранить WebSocket соединение на стороне клиента?

Tags: javascript, websocket

У меня есть класс, который создаёт websocket соединение.
Я сохраняю id установленного соединения в sessionStorage (localStorage).

```
object['class'] = class webSocket {
            constructor(name) {
                this.socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:7000");
                this.socket.onopen = function() {
                    console.log('connect is open')
                };
                this.socket.onclose = function(event) {
                    if (event.wasClean) {
                        alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
                    } else {
                        alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
                    }
                    alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
                };
                this.socket.onerror = function(error) {
                    alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
                };
                this.socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
                    let object = JSON.parse(event['data'])
                    for(let key in object){
                        switch (key) {
                            case 'WebRTC':
                                let id =  localStorage.getItem('WebRTC');
                                if( id === null){
                                    localStorage.setItem('WebRTC', object[key]['id']);
                                }
                                break
                            case 'user':
                                    let telegramSidebarLeft = new CustomEvent('telegram-sidebar-left', {
                                      detail: {
                                        slot: object
                                      }
                                    })
                                    document.dispatchEvent(telegramSidebarLeft)
                                console.log('~~~!~~~~!~~~~!~~~',key,object[key])
                                break
                            default:
                                console.warn('необрабатываемые ответы',key, object[key])
                                break
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            self() {
                return object
            }
        }
```

Но кода я делаю обновление страницы, у меня создаётся новое соединение.
Как мне сохранить на всё время сессии соединение пока я не закрою страницу ?

Дополнение:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Clients {
  clientList: {
    '8508cfe7-8b38': WebSocket {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      readyState: 3,
```

Comment: На мой взгляд это не возможно. Разве что делать на обоих (клиент и сервер) логику которая будут запоминать допустим сессию и при обновлении страницы пере-подключаться и продолжать с того места где остановились.  Не слышал такого что бы при обновлении страницы коннект оставался))))

Comment: Я дополнение к вопросу сделал. А зачем мне тогда на сервере список клиентов. с их уникальными id. У меня ведь соединение не исчезает со стороны сервера ?
Есть ли возможность проверить активные соединения на клиенте ? Пример. Я на клиенте в двух местах создаю экземпляры класса web Socket и у меня на сервере показывает двух подключенных клиентов.
Как мне на клиенте проверить существует уже соединение или нет, что бы понять, стоит его создават  или нет

Comment: Спасибо. Нашёл для себя решение которое меня устроит и работает.

Comment: По старинке для этого сокет закидывали в iframe где держалось соединение. А так-то, проще изменить серверную логику чтобы соединение восстанавливалось при перезагрузке. Ну и дабы не изобретать велосипед можно использовать уже готовые модули с использованием сессий, аля [socket.io-express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-express-session)

Comment: Я изменил уже сервер. Мне главное, что бы id при необходимости, можно было использовать один и тот же. Сейчас проблемы с этим нет уже.